# Fetch names based on comma-separated ids using laravel relations

Tags: laravel

Using Laravel Model relation retrive names based on comma separated ids, can anyone help

```
for ex

$testing= Testpage::with('relationExample')->where('id',$id)->first();

{{testing->user_ids}} -> output is -> 5,9,15,17
```

instead of comma separated ids i want to display names with comma separated from users table using laravel relations

Comment: Share all details , what is your query? and how you are tring to do?

Comment: updated my question plz check once.

Comment: Where these users name are stored?

Comment: names are stored in users table

Comment: Did you try my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You  need another query to explode by comma and make these ids as array and use `whereIn('id',$ids)`

```
$ids = explode(',',$testing->user_ids);
$users = Users::whereIn('id',$ids)->pluck('name');
$usersName = implode(',',$users);
```

Comment: i want using relations

Comment: Then you have to store each id in separate row in another pivot table.

Comment: is not possible to using relations..?

Comment: Storing data with comma separated is wrong practice. Thats why you are getting this problem.

Comment: There is a long process by using mysql `find_in_set`  but i would suggest to make db proper instead code.